# URL rewriting redirecting to a single file

Tags: php, url-rewriting

Let's say I have the project folder as follows:

```
folder/models
folder/view
folder/controls
folder/public
folder/library
```

Now let's say that the site folder is `folder/public/` and inside that folder there's just one file called `index.php`. This file handle all the site page request via the GET parameter `index.php?page=user` for example will call the user.php file of the application in another folder. The point is that I'd like that an URL such as:

> www.site.com/index.php?page=user&id=1

became

```
www.site.com/user/id/1
```

How can I do that?

Comment: @Neal, I'm using Xampp on Mac OS X... on Apache I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was taken from [CakePHP](http://www.cakephp.org) .htacess rewrite rule:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

It will render everything under your host 
http://www.site.com/* --> http://www.site.com/index.php?url=*

from here your index.php could parse $_GET['url']

```
//e.g browser requests www.site.com/user/id/1

$url = $_GET['url']; // user/id/1
$params = explode("/",$url); // array(0=>"user",1=>"id",2=>"1")
```

Comment: you may want to check out php's $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] variable!

Comment: `?url=$1` is not really necessary. You can access the same info thru `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteRule ^user/id/([0-9]+)$ index.php?page=user&id=$1
```

But it sounds to me that you should use so called router, redirect all trafic to index.php...

http://anantgarg.com/2009/03/13/write-your-own-php-mvc-framework-part-1/ (check out this link)

Answer (score 0):

In your case there is no point in using `/id/`, but here you go:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/id/(.*) index.php?page=$1&id=$2
```

Or what's a way better approach:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) index.php
```

Then handle the request in your `index.php` file by checking `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` against the patter you dream up.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using *Apache* as web server?

If yes you can use *mod_rewrite* to accomplish that.

I have not done this myself, so I can't give you detailed instructions, but searching with *google*, using a search string like `"mod_rewrite examples"` lands you a lot of seemingly good tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

Without apache rewrite rule, a micro framework named [Slim](https://github.com/codeguy/Slim) can makes routing and templating for your php project. You'll define your routes only in index.php file. Like ;

```
Slim::get('/', function () {
    Slim::render('index.template');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You will be implementing what is called the Front Controller pattern. If you Google that you will find several php implementations. I thought this series on building your own php framework was good.

http://fuelyourcoding.com/php-frameworks-just-roll-your-own-part-1/